# How can I get a photo from an iPad (iOS 5) to my Mac?

Tags: backup, photos

I am trying to get a photo from my husband's old iPad to my MacBook Pro. I have backed up his iPad to my computer and iCloud, but can't find the photos anywhere? I tried looking for a MobileSync file on my computer, but one doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app such as **[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)** to browse your iTunes backups.

1. Select **Explore iTunes Backups**.

   [image]
2. Your photos will be in **MediaDomain** → **Media** → **DCIM**.

   [image]